# Run Android App on Multiple Emulator Instances

Tags: android, virtual, device

I am using Android Studio and Android Virtual Device in order to test my app.

What I need is to use multiple emulator instances because I need to test devices with different phone numbers. What I need is to install the app on both opened emulator instances.

How can I do that? I search and tried some solutions, but I could not make it work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, get your emulator names by doing:

```
adb devices
```

Then install your app to the device/emulator you want with

```
adb -s <device/emulator ID> install <app-location>/<app-name>
```

-s means the source, which you will pick.

Hope this helps!